# How do I catch an exception being thrown in a setter bound to a VisualForce input?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have a property that is tied to an SObject like so:

```
public Decimal latitude {
  get {
    return (Decimal)self.get('latitude__c');
  }
  set {
    self.put('latitude__c', value);
  }
}
```

In a VisualForce page, I have an input field that is bound to this property.

```
<apex:inputtext value="{!latitude}" />
```

If I enter a string into this field like `abc` there is an exception in the setter, but I can't seem to catch it. The form is submitted, it's action doesn't succeed, but there is no error message. How do I catch this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add some error checking on form submit, that would validate all inputs and then display an error on the page?

Something like

```
try{
   latitude = Decimal.valueOf(latitude);
}catch (exception e){
   ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.Error, 'Invalid latitude entered!'));  
}
```

Maybe even put this code in the latitude's setter.

Comment: I have been using a custom page message component instead of the `<apex:pagemessages />` tag and that was the problem. As far as I can tell, there is no way to catch the exception during form submission and the only approach that works is to add the `<apex:pagemessages />` into the page also. I agree that checking the inputs before submission makes sense in addition.